# C++ Xcode, how to include and declare my object

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I edited my original message to include my code exactly as it is. Sorry for the troubles.

this is where I'm trying to use a pointer to a class which I added to my project:

```
#ifndef MYAPP_DivGameLayer_h
#define MYAPP_DivGameLayer_h

// When you import this file, you import all the cocos2d classes
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "Box2D.h"
#include "DivBall.h"    

#define PTM_RATIO 32
#define GRAVITY -10.0f
#define VELOCITY_ITERS 8
#define POSITION_ITERS 1
#define BALLS_COUNT 2

class DivGameLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayer {

public:

    ~DivGameLayer();
    DivGameLayer();

    // returns a Scene that contains the layer as the only child
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();

    // functions for handling user input touches    
    virtual void ccTouchesEnded(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);

    // game update loop function
    void update(float dt);

private:

    // CONSTANTS
    float SCREEN_WIDTH;
    float SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    b2World* world;                 // the game's world
    DivBall* balls;                 // balls
    int next;                       // pointer to next ball

    // initialize the game's world
    void initWorld();

    // initialize balls
    void initBalls();
};
#endif
```

and this is my DivBall header file:

```
#ifndef MYAPP_DivBall_h
#define MYAPP_DivBall_h

#include "DivGameLayer.h"

#define PATH "ball.png"
#define DENSITY 0.25f
#define FRICTION 0.1f
#define RESTITUTION 0.7f

class DivBall : public cocos2d::CCSprite {

public:

    ~DivBall();
    DivBall(DivGameLayer layer, b2World* world, cocos2d::CCPoint location, float Vx, float Vy, float omega);

private:

    DivBall();    
    b2Body* body;

};

#endif
```

this is DivBall.cpp:

```
#include "DivBall.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

using namespace cocos2d;
using namespace CocosDenshion;

// defualt CTOR
DivBall::DivBall()
{

}

// CTOR
DivBall::DivBall(DivGameLayer layer, b2World* world, CCPoint location, float Vx, float Vy, float omega)
{
    CCSprite *sprite = CCSprite::create(PATH);
    sprite->setPosition( CCPointMake(location.x, location.y) );
    layer->addChild(sprite);

    // Define the dynamic body.
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.userData = sprite;
    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Define a circle shape for our dynamic body.
    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = (sprite->getContentSize().width/2.0f)/PTM_RATIO;


    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &circle;
    fixtureDef.density =  DENSITY;
    fixtureDef.friction = FRICTION;
    fixtureDef.restitution = RESTITUTION;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    // set velocity
    body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(Vx/PTM_RATIO, Vy/PTM_RATIO));
    body->SetAngularVelocity(omega);
}

// DCTOR
DivBall::~DivBall()
{
        // nothing...
}
```

and I get a compilation error in GameLayer: unknown type name Ball.

Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Can you show the content of the `foo.h` header?

Comment: Well, most likely because your `foo.h` does not provide a valid type `foo`?

Comment: @us2012: I see mutual header inclusion as the most likely problem here

Comment: Ah, possibly. We'll see...

Comment: Wow, I guess I really got spoiled with Java and Eclipse... What needs to be in foo.h in order to make it a valid type ??

Comment: @user1541941: Please, show the content of `foo.h`. We can't help you if we can't see your code

Comment: there's nothing in foo.h I just added the files: foo.h and foo.cpp

Comment: sorry, wait a moment please...

Comment: So if there is nothing, why do you expect `foo` to be a recognized type name?

Comment: I guess I just expected the compiler to tell me what i need to add... Can you please tell me what I need to add ? default CTOR, destractor, copy CTOR... I guess i'm just used to the compiler being a little more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created some class of my own, say foo

No, you haven't. You only created a header file and and implementation file. As you mention in the comments:

> there's nothing in foo.h I just added the files: foo.h and foo.cpp

Well, then the compiler is telling you `foo` is an unknown type name, and that makes sense since you haven't defined any type named `foo`. Your `foo.h` header is empty. Just add a type named `foo` to that header, for instance:

```
class foo
{
    // Whatever...
};
```

**EDIT:**

After the update, it is now clearer what the problem is. In the definition of your `DivGameLayer` class, you declare a member variable of type `DivBall*`. However, the `DivBall.h` header is not included by the header where `DivGameLayer` is defined. Therefore, while processing that class definition, the type `DivBall` is unknown.

You should add a forward-declaration for it:

```
class DivBall; // <== ADD THIS

class DivGameLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayer 
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: I apologize. I didn't explain myself. Please excuse me. I'll get the code in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you for helping. WOW, this is a very unfriendly world compared to what I'm used to from Java\Eclipse :(

Comment: @user1541941: Yes, C++'s compilation model is bad. Hopefully the next Standard will change things.

Comment: Thanks man that helped me a lot. I coudn't find out what I'm doing wrong. So this is a downside of c++ classes :) As mostly java programmer I didn't see this coming.